# How to set Azure Active Directory for LDAPS with Location?

Tags: azure, entra-id

I am new on Azure and confused while set LDAPS.
After attach PFX succesfully, I get External IP that contain Location like East US/40.88.209.246

[image]

And while I try to set nsg's source IP : East US/40.88.209.246, a Malformed IP address error occurs.

[image]

How to solve this issue or how to set External IP without any Location ?

Comment: Did you  try  removing the Location before the IP? source IP addresses / CIDR ranges: in this field we need to give a valid IP address or range for your environment

Comment: Yes I tried and I can set nsg source IP with 40.88.209.246. But while I try to fetch using `ldapsearch -x -D "user_one@fortezhuo.onmicrosoft.com" -W -p 636 -h 40.88.209.246 -b "dc=fortezhuo,dc=onmicrosoft,dc=com" -s sub "(objectclass=*)"` nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

While configuring the NSG you have to provide a valid ip address range for your environment/organization. You can refer the below tutorial to configure LDAPS.

**Note:** Please provide the Source IP range that you are using not the Secure LDAP external IP (Used for external access). You can type "my ip" in google to get ip that you are using.

**Reference:**

[Tutorial - Configure LDAPS for Azure Active Directory Domain Services | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-configure-ldaps#lock-down-secure-ldap-access-over-the-internet)